# Своя форма подписки. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Возможно, кто то сталкивался с созданием своей формы подписки для Wordpress. Гуглю, но в основном везде предлагают плагины, а нужно свое.

Что именно хочу сделать:
1) после заполнения формы, чтобы сохранялось в базе
2) При возможности выводить в админке список всех подписчиков
3) Не показывать больше форму если подписался.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Если вы боитесь плагинов, учитесь писать свой код. Если пока не можете, нанимайте фрилансеров. Вопрос не соответствует правилам сообщества, поскольку не видно, что вы сами сделали для его решения.

Comment: Как вариант, [Contact Form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) + [Flamingo](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/).

Для 1 и 2 должно подойти.